# Can't delete the Array if it's already found(Array Searching Sorting)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search

My job is to create a program that the user will input a number and it will search the inputted number
in my Array Storage; If it is there, it will say "Found" and Display all the elements in array and delete the Found value;

Its like this:
[image]

I already done with my code but there's a problem;
If its found It doesn't display all the elements of array and not deleting it.
There's a error occur

[image]

By the way, here my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] ArrayApp = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
            16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

    System.out.println("ArrayList:");
    for (int x = 0; x < ArrayApp.length; x++) {
        System.out.print(ArrayApp[x] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < ArrayApp.length; x++) {
        if (ArrayApp[x] == num) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (x == ArrayApp.length) {
        System.out.println("Cant find: " + num);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Found");
    }

    for (int k = x; k < ArrayApp.length; k++) {
        ArrayApp[k] = ArrayApp[k + 1];

    }

    for (x = 0; x < ArrayApp.length; x++) {
        System.out.print(ArrayApp[x] + " ");
    }

}
```

So could you help me to find out, what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayApp[k] = ArrayApp[k + 1];` would throw the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when k = ArrayApp.lenngth-1, since k+1 would be out of range.

You should change the range :

```
for (int k = x; k < ArrayApp.length - 1; k++) {
    ArrayApp[k] = ArrayApp[k + 1];
}
```

And when printing the output array, if you removed an element, you don't want to print the last element, since it would be printed twice (as the length of the array doesn't change).

```
int length = ArrayApp.length;
if (x < ArrayApp.length) // adjust the number of elements to be printed after
                         // one element was removed
    length--;
for (x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    System.out.print(ArrayApp[x] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this correction.
And yes it's printing the last element twice.
How could i debug it?

Comment: @repsajznav The second snippet of code in my answer would prevent it from printing the last element twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following line is the issue.

```
ArrayApp[k] = ArrayApp[k + 1];
```

You are trying to access k+1, in case k = arraylength - 1, the access will result in **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException** as you are trying to access an element with index on available (i.e. array indexes are 0  to length-1 )

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop from

```
for (int k = x; k < ArrayApp.length; k++) {
    ArrayApp[k] = ArrayApp[k + 1];
}
```

TO

```
for (int k = x; k < ArrayApp.length - 1; k++) {
    ArrayApp[k] = ArrayApp[k + 1];
}
ArrayApp[k] = -1;//reset last element to -1 as you removed the xth element you found.
```